# Search terms separated from rest of the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("[title*='A-title-im-not-interested-in']").closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr("style","visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important;");
$("[title*='Second-title-no-need']").closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr("style","visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important;");
$("[title*='Third-i-dont-want-to-see']").closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr("style","visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important;");
$("[title*='4thtitle']").closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr("style","visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important;");
```

I'm using the above code to hide the titles I don't want. Each is in a separate line, with all of the stuff repeating what needs to be done when there is a match.
Is there a way to achieve the same result where I could list my titles to one place, and keep the what-to-do code separated? Something like this?

```
$("[title*=MYTITLES]").closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr("style","visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important;");
MYTITLES {'A-title-im-not-interested-in','Second-title-no-need','Third-i-dont-want-to-see','4thtitle'};
```

Comment: Could you please share your html code to debug easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try something like

```
var titles = ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3'];

$("[title]").filter(function(){
   return titles.indexOf(this.title) >-1;
}).closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr("style","visibility: hidden !important; display: none !important;");
```

Or

```
$.each(titles, function(_, title){
    $('[title="' + title + '"]').closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr...
})
```

Or

```
var selector = titles.map(function(title){
     return '[title="' + title + '"]';
}).join()
$(selector).closest("div.parentdivofproduct").attr...
```

Comment: Might be better to add a class instead if you need to undo this. Set those css properties in class rule

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a single jQuery selection by using an array of several elements. Instead you need to iterate through an array using each element with a different query.

So you could use anything from a for loop, `$.map`, `$.each`, `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.every`...etc